# What is the best way of organizing the loopings?

Tags: python, interactive

I have data for 12 instruments grouped as 3x4 (4 instruments for each group: N1, N2, N3, N4; C1, C2, C3, C4; S1, S2, S3, S4;). Each instrument has 2 sets of data: H and T. The dataset comes from different excel spreadsheets.

What is the best way to perform this interaction? Creating a dictionary, a matrix, using the lists...? In Matlab I would create 3 matrices with 4 columns each, but I don't know how to do this on Python (just started using it).

First I am trying to create the variables described above (N1, C3, S4...) and appending the values from different excel spreadsheets:

```
sheets = ['S_WH', 'C_WH', 'N_WH']
for i in sheets:
    path = r"\\uniwa.uwa.edu.au\userhome\students2\22371812\My Documents\Documents\FieldTechniques"
    filename = i + '.xlsx'
    sheetHeights = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(path,filename), data_only=True)
    heights = sheetHeights.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

    Time=[]
    H1=[]
    H2=[]
    H3=[]
    H4=[]

    for row in range (2, heights.max_row+1):
        Time.append(heights['A' + str(row)].value)
        H1.append(heights['B' + str(row)].value)
        H2.append(heights['C' + str(row)].value)
        H3.append(heights['D' + str(row)].value)
        H4.append(heights['E' + str(row)].value)
```

First of all, how do I get those lists (H1, H2...) and append to a dictionary (that's how I thought it could be the best way) for each one of the sheets?

Secondly, I have to do the same for T values, so all the stations will have H and T related to it. A third value would be S, that is the sum of H and T. I don't know how to do this either. If someone could help me (even giving some hints) it would be great.

Comment: Best approach is trying something, and if you run into a specific problem then coming and asking about it here.

Comment: and the error is?

Comment: I just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

*Best* is a bit ambiguous here. `Lists` have their pros & cons, and so do `dictionaries`, `arrays`, and every other data structure.

The best structure depends on what you need (minimal memory, minimal search time and so on).

As long as no major constraint is introduced, I would go with what I think is the simplest solution - dictionary that holds a key and a 3-values list as its value - `{instrument : [H,T,S]}`

Toy example:

```
N1,N2 = 'a','b'
H_N1, H_N2 = 1,2
T_N1, T_N2 = 10,20

instruments = [N1, N2]
# assuming you already have H,T saved
H = [H_N1, H_N2]
T = [T_N1, T_N2]

# create an list S, and fill it using list comprehension
S = [H[i] + T[i]  for i in range(len(T))]

# can also be done by a loop
S = []
for i in range(len(T)):
    S.append(T[i] + H[i])

# add the lists together so they would all be stored together as a dictionary value
zip1 = zip(H,T,S)
zip2 = zip(instruments, zip1)
d = dict((key,value) for (key,value) in zip2)
print d
```

Output = `{'a': (1, 10, 11), 'b': (2, 20, 22)}`

Comment: That's a good way. I am trying to fill the S for each instrument (H+T) but I don't know how to build the loop. Sorry, I know this is basic, but I am new in Python, after years on Matlab

Comment: show how you would matlab it, or better yet, show your erroneous python loop